# Is there any difference between "in a week " and "next week"?

Tags: grammar

1. Let's meet in a week.
2. Let's meet next week

Does sentences above have a same meaning ?

Comment: _Next week_ refers to a calendric week -- one that begins on Sunday and ends on Saturday -- and means any time from next Sunday morning to the next Saturday night. _In a week_ refers to a non-calendric week -- one that begins any time and ends exactly seven days later -- and means any time in the next seven days.

Comment: Also, “in a week” means “seven days into the future from the current point in time”, whereas “next week” means “any time between the Monday morning and Sunday night that comes after whatever point in time is considered the frame of reference in a given context”. @JohnLawler Or more commonly one that begins on Monday and ends on Sunday.

Comment: Right. The "business week" is composed of "business days" and may be either calendric or non-calendric.

Answer (score 2):

"Next week" is within 7 days from next Monday. "In a week" means just in 7 days.

Answer (score 1):

I am living in Texas but was born and raised in Canada. My husband and I have problems with the difference between 'this week' and 'next week'.

If I want to watch *60 Minutes* on TV this coming Sunday, (today is Monday), I'd say. "I want to watch it this week." My American husband would say he wants to see it "next week". I'd understand that to mean not this coming Sunday, but the Sunday after that. He means this coming Sunday.

So, my answer is that it is confusing and it depends on where you live. However, I also think in writing that rule is likely different than in everyday speech.

Comment: It sounds like he considers Sunday to be the first day of the week. If today is Tuesday and _60 Minutes_ aired on Fridays, it would be exceedingly uncommon (and absolutely certain to garner misunderstandings) to refer to the episode that airs in three days as “next week’s”. But since Sunday is considered the first day of the week by some, it makes sense the way you describe it. That's not really related to the difference between “in a week” and “next week”, though.